# Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Tags: php, strpos

I don't know what happen `eror_log` generate, but code works fine, but log is make me curious

> PHP Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/abc/public_html/url.php on line 46

the line 46 is:

> `if (strpos($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/') === FALSE) {`

Here's the code:

```
$headers = @get_headers($url, 1); // @ to suppress errors. Remove when debugging.
if (isset($headers['Content-Type'])) {
  if (strpos($headers['Content-Type'], 'image/') === FALSE) {
    // Not a regular image (including a 404).
  }
  else {
    // It's an image!
    header("Location: ".$url);
    die();
  }
}
else {
  // No 'Content-Type' returned.
}
```

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($headers['Content-Type']);` ?

Comment: Was there still an issue? Could you leave a comment, or -- if you got the answer -- mark one of the answers as accepted?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]` to get content-type if request is POST.

Comment: Look at the second parameter again.

Answer (score 3):

Some response headers may have multiple values, you could for instance get this:

```
$headers["Content-Type"]=>  array {
   [0]=>    "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
   [1]=>    "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
}
```

So, you'll need to detect that, for instance by testing with `is_array`.

Note that the above is for working with *response* headers, i.e. what the server returns as content type, not what the client might be *requesting* as content type.

If on the other hand you need the content type of the *current* request (i.e. *$url* is the current request's URL), the use of [`get_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) is not the way to go about. It launches an HTTP request to the given URL to retrieve headers from the server. But since that is a request you are already processing, that cannot return useful information. Also, response headers do not generally rely on information the client browser would have (e.g. whether the request originates from an `img` tag).

In case you need information about the current request, you could use one of (or combination of) the following instead:

- $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]
- $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']
- [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) (= getallheaders())

each with their own pros and cons.